# No volumes are attached to running mysql docker container - AWS Elastic beanstalk multi container docker app

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, docker-volume

My current approach:

The Dockerrun.aws.json file looks like this:

```
{
  "AWSEBDockerrunVersion": 2,
  "volumes": [
    {
      "name": "mysql-volume",
      "host": {
        "sourcePath": "/var/app/current/web-app"
      }
    }
  ],
  "containerDefinitions": [
    {
      "name": "mysql",
      "image": "mysql:5.7",
      "environment": [
        {
          "name": "MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD",
          "value": "root"
        },
        {
          "name": "MYSQL_USER",
          "value": "user"
        },
        {
          "name": "MYSQL_PASSWORD",
          "value": "pass"
        },
        {
          "name": "MYSQL_DATABASE",
          "value": "db"
        }
      ],
      "essential": true,
      "memory": 256,
      "portMappings": [
        {
          "hostPort": 3306,
          "containerPort": 3306
        }
      ],
      "mountPoints": [
        {
          "sourceVolume": "mysql-volume",
          "containerPath": "/var/lib/mysql"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "web-application",
      "image": "some image",
      "essential": true,
      "memory": 512,
      "portMappings": [
        {
          "hostPort": 80,
          "containerPort": 8080
        }
      ],
      "links": [
        "mysql"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

When I connect via SSH to EC2 instance I see that no volumes are created. Not sure, what's the reason and how can I change the *Dockerrrun.aws.json* file to make it work. Also, when I stop and restart the instance the data is lost